# req.body is empty when making a post request via http.request

Tags: node.js, request, express

I have a nodejs app using bodyparser(), and this route :

```
app.post('/users', function(req, res){
  res.json(req.body)
})
```

when i curl

```
curl -X POST 127.0.0.1:3000/users -d 'name=batman'
```

server sends back this json :

```
{ name: 'batman' }
```

my problem is when trying to make the same request with http.request, req.body is empty
i'm doing the same call though, here is a test.js file that i run with node :

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3000,
  path: '/api/users',
  method: 'POST'
};

var request = http.request(options, function (response) {
  var str = '';
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
});

request.end("name=batman");
```

request body is empty -> `{}`

why ? i've tried setting content-length but does not do anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to pass a `Content-Type` to tell `bodyParser()` which parser to use. For regular form data, you should use `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so:

```
var options = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3000,
  path: '/api/users',
  method: 'POST',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};
```

Should do the trick.

**Edit:** If you find yourself doing a lot of client HTTP requests in node, I heartily recommend [Mikeal Rogers' `request` module](https://github.com/mikeal/request), which makes these things a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure these lines are present in your `app.js` or `server.js`

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```