# Node.js req.body is blank

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have tried the threads on [Node "req is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081539/node-req-is-not-defined) and [req.body is empty when making a post request via http.request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039166/req-body-is-empty-when-making-a-post-request-via-http-request) and similar, but the problem remains.

The server side code:

```
var express = require('express');  
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');  
var validator = require('validator');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));  
app.use(bodyParser.json());  
app.use(function(req, res, next) {  
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
});

app.post('/sampleurl', function (req, res) {  
    var reqbody = req.body;
    console.log(reqbody);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);  
console.log("listening");
```

What I send (using hurl.it):

[image: post request]
[image: response]

What I get back from the server (the console.log):

```
listening
{}
```

Comment: Try defining `reqbody` as `req.test` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried your code.. It is perfectly fine..

What you are missing is adding headers in request.

Add `Content-Type` header as `application/json`[image]

Answer (score 2):

To extend the other answer, which is correct, body-parser checks the `Content-Type` before trying to parse the HTTP body.

If you'd like to change this behavior, you can have body-parser attempt to parse any input into json regardless of the `Content-Type`:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: '*' }));
```

The wildcard `*` will tell it to try to parse on any type: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions

Comment: Great method! Thank you for your answer.